# Legalese: Place the preposition closer to the verb to make the text shorter?

Tags: prepositions, legalese

In the dense legalese of a product license I found the following sentence:

> The subscriber shall not disclose to, or permit the use of, the Licensed Rights by any third party.

I assume what is meant is

> The subscriber shall not disclose the Licensed Rights **to** or permit the use **of** the Licensed Rights by any third party.

Does this grammatical trick of placing the preposition closer to the verb, so that the noun can be omitted in the first occurence, have a name? Is this considered "proper" outside the special language of terms and conditions?

Comment: I’d say it’s wrong even for legalese.

Comment: Yes; 'The subscriber shall not disclose to the Licensed Rights by any third party' is unacceptable, and therefore so is the original.

Comment: I assume it means "The subscriber shall not disclose the Licensed Rights *to any third party*." and "The subscriber shall not permit the use of the Licensed Rights *by any third party*." but you seem to have highlighted different prepositions in the two parts. This sort of construction only works if the structure is obvious, and this example isn't good.